# Stylecop not reading Stylecop.settings for one project in multiproject solution

Tags: msbuild, stylecop

I've been banging my head against this for a few hours.

I have a bunch of projects within a solution, with a settings.stylecop in the solution directory.

For the other projects (in the same solution) where I have StyleCop enabled (by adding the targets into the .csproj file) the settings in the solution directory are being read. For just one project this doesn't seem to happening (some of my "ignored" rules are being run).

Adding a settings.stylecop to the project directory doesn't help (nor does editing it via the VS2012 menu).

I've tried building the files using msbuild and the other projects are fine but it still gives errors.

Interestingly inside the VS IDE when I run StyleCop by clicking on the menu option it aborts with a cancelled error due to the project having more than 1000 warnings and then if change the limit in the settings.stylecop in the root then it will actually complete.

Also in VS if I run StyleCop from the menu the warnings in the error pane get doubled up, but I'm not sure if this a Resharper artefact.

So somewhere something is misconfigured (and I've scoured the .csproj to see if I can find it) but I'm a bit stumped as where to look next, anyone got any ideas? Does stylecop have any means of starting from a different settings.stylecop that can be set in a project?

Comment: Found it. Message I thought was turned off wasn't and I suspect there was some resharper caching fun.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was trying to suppress some of the "this." warnings and there are two options for this which was causing me to misdiagnose.

Also I suspect that resharper was confusing some things.